# What is brandbot?

Tags: centos, services

What is the "brandbot" service running in Centos 7? What does it do? All I can find (it has no manpage) is "Flexible Branding Service" and that it's part of the "base" repo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`brandbot`: tool to write branding to `/etc/os-release`
When you start it<sup>1</sup>, it looks for /var/lib/rhsm/branded_name and adds in `/etc/os-release`:

```
PRETTY_NAME=first_line_from_branded_name
```

<sup>1</sup>**Path-based activation** — System services that support path-based activation can be started on-demand when a particular file or directory changes its state. Systemd uses path units for path-based activation.

Answer (score 3):

It is a tool that write branding to `/etc/os-release` which in turn [*contain operating system identification data*](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html).